# C# Correct Way of Binding a List to a ListBox

Tags: c#, forms, button, listbox

Assume I have the following code:

```
        private List<Employee> displayEmp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            displayEmp = new List<Employee>();
        }
```

In my Add Button handler:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] selection = comboEmail.GetItemText(comboEmail.SelectedItem).Split(',');

            Employee add = new Employee(Convert.ToInt32(selection[0]), selection[1], selection[2], selection[3]);

            if (!(comboEmail.SelectedIndex == 0))
            {

                if(!(listEmail.Items.Contains(add))){

                      displayEmp.Add(add);;
                      listEmail.DataSource = null;
                      listEmail.DataSource = displayEmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(add.ToString() + " Already Added.");
                }

            }

        }
```

My Remove Button Handler:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int indexRemoval = listEmail.SelectedIndex;

    if (indexRemoval != -1)
    {
        displayEmp.RemoveAt(indexRemoval);
        listEmail.DataSource = null;
        listEmail.DataSource = displayEmp;
    }

}
```

I have a list of employees in a ComboBox that when selected, I add to a listbox. In the my add/remove button handlers, am I doing it correctly? What is the proper practice when you have a collection binded to a control, and you want to add/remove items?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are binding your collection correctly.

I would also do:

```
listEmail.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Name being whatever property within 'Employee' you want displayed in the listbox, else it will try to convert the object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> displayEmp;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayEmp = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        // you need to assign DataSource only once
        listEmail.DataSource = displayEmp;
    }
```

ObservableCollection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, that informs ListView about all changes in collection (adding and removing intems).
As ObservableCollection informs about changes, you don't need to forcefully refresh bindings so there is no need for

```
    listEmail.DataSource = null;
    listEmail.DataSource = displayEmp;
```